# Why is Souma's hand steaming and burnt looking?

Tags: wagnaria

In Working!! - 3rd Season - Episode 13, why is Souma's hand steaming and burnt looking?
[image]

We can see that the only contact he had with Inami was touching her shoulder.
[image]
[image]

At first I thought he had taken a punch with his hand or something, but after watching the scene a few times I can't figure it out.

Comment: Perhaps a reference to Inami's intense body heat, which we saw melting the chocolates in her hand back in Series I.

Comment: I think it's analogizing Souma and Inami are like the undead and holy water or sunlight and vampires. They don't (or rather can't) get along naturally. The joke here is probably since Souma avoids Inami like she's a plague, because he doesn't want to get hit by her, he probably developed a natural weakness to her.